# How to navigate to home page while click on the header image under stack navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to navigate the home page while clicking on the header image. The image is under the stack navigator in App.js file

Answer (score 0):

Put this code onto the page you want to have the button to go back

```
static navigationOptions = {
    {navigation} = this.props
    headerTitle: <YourTitleComponent/>,
    headerRight: (
      <YourClickableComponentWithTheImage
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('toTheScreenYouWant'}
      />
    ),
  };
```

You can use HeaderLeft too, and change the title component to a simple String